# Animation on EditText

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

I'm trying to make a custom animation on an EditText. I'm just trying to make an EditText wider when I touch it (just like the search box on top of the the twitter web).

The only solution i've think is to create my own Animation subclass and implement there... but.. is there another solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [scaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html)?

Comment: I'm using a edittext with a custom drawable background with rounded corners... I suppose that when I scale the rounded corners will get deformed?